# How to make a Reactjs header accessible

Tags: react-redux, accessibility, jsx

I am running axe in my Chrome dev tools to find the markup that is lacking to make my website more accessible. Right now JAWS cannot read certain pages. I am making slow progress as I am looking at this bit of code here:

```
return [
      <ul className="breadcrumb" key="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
        <li><a href={backHref} className="link-back" tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="back-to-page">{backText}</span></a></li>
        <li><span>&bull;</span></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com" target="_blank"  tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="section-name">Guest Services</span></a></li>
      </ul>,
      <a href="/" className={`link-home ${logoHrefStatus}`} key="eatHere"  tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="screen-reader-text">Eat Here</span></a>
    ];
  }
```

which axe is saying this element is not visible to screen readers and needs an `aria-label` attribute or an `aria-labeledby` attribute. I have tried the fix below:

```
return [
      <ul role="tablist" className="breadcrumb" key="breadcrumb">
        <li role="presentation"><a href={backHref} role="tab" aria-selected="true" className="link-back" tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="back-to-page">{backText}</span></a></li>
        <li><span>&bull;</span></li>
        <li><a href="https://example.com" target="_blank"  tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="section-name">Guest Services</span></a></li>
      </ul>,
      <a href="/" className={`link-home ${logoHrefStatus}`} key="eatHere"  tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="screen-reader-text">Eat Here</span></a>
    ];
  }
```

to no avail.

Comment: In the first code snippet, which element is aXe complaining about, exactly?  Can you please post the HTML as it is rendered in the browser (not the react code).  Also the CSS for the classes here - I'm especially interested in what properties the `screen-reader-text` class uses.

Comment: Aside, there are so many unusual things here that are invalid, unnecessary or confusing for accessibility.  (1) Overriding the UL semantics with a navigation role breaks the list semantics. (2) the tablist role should only be used if you actually have tab panels too. (3) Only one of your links is treated with a tab role, so it's a weird mix of tabs and list items (4) the tab role doesn't make sense for a "back-to-page" link.

Comment: (5) Going by the link names, the use of tabindex looks unnecessary and probably dangerous.

Comment: (6) The list item which only contains a bullet is strange.

Comment: Overall, it's hard to tell what you are actually trying to build here, and all of these things are likely to cause confusion for screen reader users.  However, these aren't actually relevant to the question you have asked about `aria-label`.

Comment: @andrewmacpherson, when I use `axe`, I get this error: `aria-label attribute does not exist or is empty`, so I am just wondering how do I add it in this context where `axe` is complaining that the with a `className="link_back"` does not have text that is readable by a screen reader.

Comment: Is there ever a situation where a back-to-page link isn't needed?  I'm wondering if `{backText`} is ever empty, which would result in a link without an accessible name.

Comment: The aXe message is a bit misleading. There's no requirement for an aria-label, specifically.  What is required is for every link to have a meaningful name.  Ideally, this will come from the link element content, i.e. `{backText}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may actually be as simple as:

```
<li><a href={backHref} aria-label="link-back" className="link-back" tabIndex={tabIndex}><span className="back-to-page">{backText}</span></a></li>
```

Give that a try.

Comment: This is risky.  The link text is a variable (`{backText}`, but your aria-label is a fixed value.  What's more, your aria-label doesn't make much sense as a UI string.  Remember that the aria-label overrides the link text when the accessible name is computed.  If they differ, there's a risk of failing WCAG [SC 2.5.2 Label in name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html).